# Nesting Classes

Tags: java, class, inner-classes, nested

If I nest a class inside another, does the nested class automatically become a subclass of the parent class? Would the nested class have access to all the public methods, vairables of the parent class?

Oh sorry - the programming language i am referring mainly to is Java!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I nest a class inside another, does the nested class automatically become a subclass of the parent class?

No

> Would the nested class have access to all the public methods, vairables of the parent class?

If the inner class is not static, yes.  It also has access to any other members, static or not, and public or not.  If the nested class is declared static then there is no enclosing instance, so it would only have access to the static members of the outer ("parent") class.

Comment: just 8 seconds ago . :). but you are fast typer than me. :)

Comment: does it work the other way too? does the outer class have access to the inner classes methods/variables without instantiating the inner class?

Comment: The inner class, if it is not static, will also implicitly contain a reference to the outer class, and therefore cannot be instantiated without one (which you'll find if you're trying to do this with reflection, for example). If it's static, there is no such reference.

Answer (score 2):

Nested class is not subclass of parent class. If nested class is not static , it can access all methods and variables of the parent class. If nested class is static, then it can access only static fields and methods.

Answer (score 1):

What language is this in reference to? For most languages, an inner class and a subclass are completely different things. An inner class is a "member" of the outer class, just as fields and methods are members of the outer class. And just like any (static) method of the outer class can access all (static) class members, usually inner classes have access, as members of the outer class, to all other members of the outer class. (This is definitely not true of all OO languages, however.)